# Duplicate key error in Mongo Sharded Cluster

Tags: mongodb, distributed

I'm running into duplicate key error in Mongo Sharded Cluster(MSC) which does not happen when working with Mongo Replica Set.

I have simple operation in client app:

```
// pseudocode - email is unique key
subscriber = db.newsletter.find({email: "john@smith.com"})
if (subscriber == null) {
  db.newsletter.insert({email: "john@smith.com", name: "John"})
} else {
  db.newsletter.update({email: "john@smith.com"}, {name: "John"})
}
```

I did not include it in above code but I need to retrieve _id of a document so using upsert is not an option.

**Error**:
If above process is executed twice for the same and new email it would cause duplicate key error. Second iteration will not be able to find subscriber therefore it will attempt to insert despite document already existing in collection.

As far as I know, having single instance of above client running should not cause duplicate key error, but it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be the job of the [findAndModify command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/#dbcmd.findAndModify), or the [findOneAndUpdate method](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/).

There is an `upsert` flag, which will create the document if it doesn't exist. You would also have to use the `new` flag, to return the new document if it is created.

Comment: Just to be clear: find does not find anything but insert throws duplicate key error because of concurrent nature of the process. Afaik `upsert` does not return document so I don't see how I would retrieve `_id` if document already exists.

Comment: @xReprisal : I haven't gotten to the bottom of your isolated problem, but anyway you will somehow need to wrap your actions into some form of transaction. `findAndModify` is a built-in command which does this (find and update in one go, and also "create if not exists" with the `upsert` flag). Additionally, the documentation specifically states that it `modifies and returns a single document`, which is the second part of your need.

Comment: You're right, I did not read your answer carefully enough. I though you were talking about `upsert` method not the flag. Sorry for that. Looks like that's the solution I was looking for. Thanks for help.